# How to write multiple elements into one cell using xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, excel, list, xlsxwriter

Im using xlsx writer

I have a list of lists, something like this:

lst = [[aaa1,aaa2,aaa3],[bbb1,bbb2,bbb3]]

I want to write the list's first element([aaa1,aaa2,aaa3]) to a single cell, and so on. Here is a picture what the result should look like:

[image]

I have no idea how to do this.Thanks for your help <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify cells index:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('write_data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write(0, 0, 1234)     # Writes an int
worksheet.write(1, 0, 1234.56)  # Writes a float
worksheet.write(2, 0, 'Hello')  # Writes a string
worksheet.write(3, 0, None)     # Writes None
worksheet.write(4, 0, True)     # Writes a bool

workbook.close()
```

In your case you can use `join` and `add_format`:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('write_data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
wrap_format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})

lst = [['aaa1','aaa2','aaa3'],['bbb1','bbb2','bbb3']]
worksheet.write(0, 0, '\n'.join(lst[0]), wrap_format)
worksheet.write(1, 0, '\n'.join(lst[1]), wrap_format)

workbook.close()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Ahh u are amazing!  I have an another problem, I have a NoneType in my list and i got this error: 'TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found'.I'm working with multiple excels and if the data is None i got that message, if i remove the file with the NoneType it works well

Comment: `for index,val in enumerate(all_list):
    worksheet.write(index,0, '\n'.join(val),wrap_format)
    index += len(val)`

Comment: @huhu
You can remove ```None``` values. Pls attach your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can find everything you are looking for in the [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html) document.

```
workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filename.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet1.write('A1', 123)
workbook.close()
```